# Proof: If $(a,b)\ne 1$, then: if $a\mid c, b \mid c$ possibly implies $ ab \nmid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> 1: If $(a,b)\ne 1$, then: if $a\mid c$, & $b \mid c$ implies generally $ab \nmid c$

Have $ax+by \ne 1; c = ae, c = bf, \exists x,y,e,f \in \mathbb{Z}$. Also, can state that $c \mid ae +bf$, as obvious; hence $c \mid aex +bfy$, a linear combination.

To prove $ab \nmid c$, need that $c$ is not a linear combination of $ab$. But, $ab | abef$, as $a|ae$ & $b|bf$. However, the square root of $abef$, i.e. $c$ need be checked for divisibility by $ab$. So, unless $ab = ef$, it is true. This implies that $c$ if not a perfect square with the added condition $ab = ef$, the given statement is true.

=> Request a better proof than above.

> 2: If $(a,b)\ne 1$, then: if $a\mid bc$ implies generally that $a \nmid c$.

It is possible that $a \mid b$, i.e. $b = ae, \exists e \in \mathbb {Z}$, hence even if $a \mid bc$, it is possible that $a \nmid c$.

=> Request a better proof than above, better based on linear combinations.

Comment: False when $a = b = c = 2$.

Comment: But $c=2$ is not a perfect square, if implied for first proof.

Comment: Write out your idea succinctly and readably.  You haven't done that yet.

Comment: Are you looking for a necessary and sufficient condition that $ab\mid c$?  Because your given conditions are neither necessary nor sufficient.  To show that the set of conditions $(a,b)\neq 1, a\mid c, b\mid c$ does not imply $ab\mid c$ all you need is to give an example of where the hypotheses are satisfied but the conclusion is not, e.g. $a=4,b=6, c=12$.  Here we have $(4,6)=2\neq 1$, $4\mid 12$ and $6\mid 12$ but $24\nmid 12$.  You say later something about $c$ being or not being a perfect square, which my example here should invalidate as well.

Comment: To show that the set of conditions $(a,b)\neq 1, a\mid c, b\mid c$ does not imply $ab\nmid c$, again all you need is to give an example where the hypotheses are satisfied but the conclusion is not, e.g. $a=2,b=4,c=8$.  We have $(2,4)=2,2\mid8, 4\mid 8$ and $8\mid 8$.  Since the given hypotheses do not imply $ab\mid c$ and also do not imply $ab\nmid c$, any attempt to prove that the hypotheses *do* imply either of these must be flawed and incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, particularly that such possibly true and possibly false (even if only one case is there on any side) need no theory. Just an example is enough. But, as per my proof, if $c$ is a perfect square with the added condition that $ab = ef$ (have edited the OP), then I feel there should be no counter-example possible.

Comment: I don't know what "possibly implies generally" means.  Is it different from "implies"?  If not, you have counterexamples.

Comment: @RossMillikan It means "can be"; i.e. both yes and no. It all depends on the case.

Comment: Then you just need to quote two cases.  One can be $a=4,b=6,c=24$.  Another can be $a=2,b=2,c=2$.  Done.

Comment: Agreed, but anything wrong with my approach, or need do as @gimusi suggests to do by theory. Is my approach, hence of gimusi an overkill.

Comment: Yes your approach is wrong because you are using logical language wrongly. Be careful of the difference between “$P$ implies not $Q$” and “$P$ does not imply $Q$”.

Comment: Okay fine and thanks for pointing out this error totally out of my view, I would also request more feedback.

Comment: The mis-use of logical language is common, and you must be careful to distinguish between a statement about $all$ $a,b.c$ and a statement about any particular values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prove considering the **equivalent statements**: $\neg Q \implies \neg P$.

$ab | c \implies b \nmid \ c \lor a \nmid \ c$

$a | c \implies a \nmid \ bc$

Comment: Please note that the implication and the reverse can be true, i.e. depends on cases. Also, please elaborate as to why consider the equivalent, if both options are there.

Comment: thanks for the editing, what do you think about the statements with reverse implication?

Comment: In fact, the question is an exercise in Jones book for the case when $a$ and $b$ are not co-prime. As for $a$ and $b$ being co-prime, the given both statements are always true. I do not know how to interpret your equivalent statements. I will continue the discussion, and hope it to be a long one.

Comment: The dis-proof is possible by this implication when the lhs is true and the right one is false. But, the left side can be false or true, so it means the ambiguity (i.e., both false and true are possible based on the case) continues. This leads back to the start only.

Comment: @jiten When an implication statement is false an effective (maybe the only) way to prove is to find and to exhit at least least a counter example; thereverse implication can be useful to find counter examples. Only when it is true you have to exhibit a complete proof.

Comment: But here the reverse implication is not helping either. I do not see any chance of a counter example except that it too fails. In fact, if a theoretical reverse implication can produce any counter examples is not clear to me. Please elaborate with any example of any problem.

Comment: For the first I try for example: a=2, b=2 and c=4 and it fails. For the second I try with a=c=2, b=1.

Answer (score 0):

Easy disproof:

Set $a=b=c$ where $a > 1$.